# Write CDC data to S3 from MongoDB Atlas collections using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, spark-structured-streaming

We are trying to perform CDC(Changed Data Capture) and write that to S3 in JSON format, from all of our collections created in MongoDB Atlas(v4.4.23) deployment using Spark Structured Streaming. We are using PySpark in AWS Glue(v3.0) to run this.
Below are the dependency jars used in the streaming job.

- mongo-spark-connector_2.12-10.1.1.jar
- bson-4.10.2.jar
- mongodb-driver-core-4.10.2.jar
- mongodb-driver-sync-4.10.2.jar

However the job is failing with below exception when its being executed in AWS Glue. I ran the similar streaming job in my local system, but I did not encountered any issue.

```
ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logError(94)): Aborting task
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.conversions.Bson.toBsonDocument()Lorg/bson/BsonDocument;
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.MongoMicroBatchPartitionReader.getCursor(MongoMicroBatchPartitionReader.java:169)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.MongoMicroBatchPartitionReader.next(MongoMicroBatchPartitionReader.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.PartitionIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MetricsIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Providing below the code snippet for more clarity.

```
def write_to_filesink(batch_df, batch_id, collection, base_dir):
    batch_df.write\
            .format('json')\
            .mode('append')\
            .save(f'{base_dir}/{collection}')

base_s3_path = s3://bucket/dir1/dir2
partial_filesink_writter = partial(write_to_filesink, collection=collection, base_dir=base_s3_path)

streaming_df = spark.readStream\
                 .format('mongodb')\
                 .option('spark.mongodb.connection.uri', connection_uri)\
                 .option('spark.mongodb.database', db_name)\
                 .option('spark.mongodb.collection', collection_name) \
                 .option('spark.mongodb.change.stream.publish.full.document.only', 'true')\
                 .option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true")\
                 .load()

query = streaming_df.writeStream \
                    .foreachBatch(partial_filesink_writter) \
                    .option('checkpointLocation', \
                            f'{base_dir}/{collection}/_checkpoint') \
                    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds') \
                    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```